# How can I set an onTouchEvent separately on the objects (more than 1) drawn by onDraw() method?

Tags: android, graphics, android-canvas, android-view, paint

Supposing that I have two circles inside my onDraw() method.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawCircle(redX, redY, redRad, redPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, rad, p);
}
```

nevermind of the variables that I have used, through the method provided by the `View` class `onTouchEvent()` I can put an action on a circle if it is alone, but what if I want them to have an on `onTouchEvent()` separately even though they are at the same `onDraw()` method, is it possible? What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible as onTouchEvent is method of view class and you can override it only once. 
Only thing you can do is to override ontouchEvent and then from its touch position you can find out in which area you are touching and do the operation that you need to do.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    upCell = -1;
    xPos = event.getX();
    return true;
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        xPos = event.getX();
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {

    }
 return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the position of each object & check for overlap every time the touch event for this view is invoked.

A sample is given below(Assuming your objects are circles):

```
public class CircleDrawingView extends View
{
    //constructor - to be used when creating view from code 
    public CircleDrawingView(final Context ct) {
        super(ct);
        init();
    }

    //constructor - invoked when view is used in xml
    public CircleDrawingView(final Context ct, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(ct, attrs);
        init();
    }

    //constructor - invoked when view is used in xml    
    public CircleDrawingView(final Context ct, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(ct, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }


    Paint mCirclePaint;
    ArrayList<CircleArea> allCircles;//list of all circles drawn on the view    
    private void init() {
        allCircles = new ArrayList<>();
        //CircleArea is a class defined below. It's constructor params are:
        //CircleArea(int CenterX,int CenterY,int Radius,String TAG)
        allCircles.add( new CircleArea(150,50,50, "C1"));
        allCircles.add( new CircleArea(150,250,90, "C2"));
        allCircles.add( new CircleArea(220,550,50, "C3"));
        allCircles.add( new CircleArea(250,350,150, "C4"));

        mCirclePaint = new Paint();
        mCirclePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mCirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDraw(final Canvas canv) {
        canv.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        for (CircleArea obj : allCircles)
            canv.drawCircle(obj.centerX, obj.centerY, obj.radius, mCirclePaint);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        float xTouch = event.getX();
        float yTouch = event.getY();

        for (CircleArea obj : allCircles)
        {
            //Check if the touched co-ordinates lies in one of the drawn circle
            if(Math.abs(obj.centerX-xTouch)<obj.radius && Math.abs(obj.centerY-yTouch)<obj.radius)
            {
                onTouch(obj.tag);

                //return true; - If you want the touch event of other views to be invoked

                //return false; - If you want to consume the touch event,
                // i.e. touch event for other views will not be invoked

                //Do not return if objects(circles) drawn on this view are overlapping 
                //and you want to invoke touch event for each object if such a scenario occurs
            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private void onTouch(String tag)
    {
        switch (tag)
        {
            case "C1":
                //Touched circle 1
                break;
            case "C2":
                //Touched circle 2
                break;
            case "C3":
                //Touched circle 3
                break;
            case "C4":
                //Touched circle 4
                break;
            default:
                //Didnt touch any circle
        }
    }

    /** Stores data about single circle */
    private static class CircleArea {
        int radius;
        int centerX;
        int centerY;
        String tag;

        CircleArea(int centerX, int centerY, int radius, String tag) {
            this.radius = radius;
            this.centerX = centerX;
            this.centerY = centerY;
            this.tag = tag;
        }
    }
}
```